# How to sum values from a json field in Mariadb using JSON functions

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, mariadb

Giving the following json field in a table column:

```
[
  {
    "payment_date":"2016-04-26",
    "amount":590,
    "payment_method":"2"
  },
  {
    "payment_date":"2017-05-01",
    "amount":208,
    "payment_method":"4"
  }
]
```

How could I sum all the amounts?

The farthest I could get is

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(`payment_lines`, '$[*].amount') FROM tbl
```

which returns:

```
[590, 208]
```

What I would need to get is this sum of 590 and 208. So to say that in this case there are two rows but there might be many more.

```
SELECT VERSION();
10.2.6-MariaDB-10.2.6+maria~jessie-log
```

Comment: What version of MariaDB are you using?.

Comment: 10.2.6-MariaDB-10.2.6+maria~jessie-log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```sql
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------------------+
| VERSION()             |
+-----------------------+
| 10.2.6-MariaDB-10.2.6 |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SET @`JSON` := '
    '> [
    '>   {
    '>     "payment_date":"2016-04-26",
    '>     "amount":590,
    '>     "payment_method":"2"
    '>   },
    '>   {
    '>     "payment_date":"2017-05-01",
    '>     "amount":208,
    '>     "payment_method":"4"
    '>   }
    '> ]';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT
    ->   JsonGet_Int(
    ->     JSON_EXTRACT(@`JSON`, '$[*].amount'),
    ->     '[+]'
    ->   ) `SUM`;
+------+
| SUM  |
+------+
|  798 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

See [CONNECT JSON Table Type](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/connect-json-table-type/).

**UPDATE**

Check:

```sql
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE `Variable_name` = 'plugin_dir';
+---------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                  |
+---------------+------------------------+
| plugin_dir    | /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ |
+---------------+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> \! ls -1 /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ | grep 'ha_connect'
ha_connect.so

MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE FUNCTION IF NOT EXISTS jsonget_int RETURNS integer
    -> SONAME 'ha_connect.so';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I get the following error: `#1305 - FUNCTION tbl.JsonGet_Int does not exist`

Comment: plugin_dir: /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/, and ls /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ lists ha_connect.so correctly.

Comment: After running the last line `CREATE FUNCTION IF NOT EXISTS jsonget_int RETURNS integer SONAME 'ha_connect.so';` it started to work.. Nice one!

Comment: I'm facing the same challenge. My JSON data is looking quite similar to yours and I also need to sum up certain values, but these are decimals. So I tried to create that function: `CREATE FUNCTION IF NOT EXISTS jsonget_int RETURNS DECIMAL SONAME 'ha_connect.so';` but querying that function will crash my database service, e.g. `SELECT JsonGet_Int( JSON_EXTRACT(@json, '$.trades[*].trade.price'),'[+]') `SUM`;` Can you help me adapt your solution to sum decimals as well? I'm using MariaDB 10.3.31

Comment: @dovregubben: Try [JsonGet_Real](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connect-json-table-type/#jsonget_string-jsonget_int-jsonget_real).

Comment: @wchiquito: yes, that works fine, thank you!