# JSON_EXTRACT SUM Function

Tags: mysql, json, database, mariadb

Here is my Stored Data. I need the sum of "total". basically I need to fetch overall my sales.

[image]

here is my query which returns 0. I have read about how to use sum function but it's not working

```
USE pharmacy_db;

SELECT SUM(JSON_EXTRACT(Invoice, "$[*].total")) AS sales
FROM sales;
```

[image]

Comment: You use a MySQL JSON function to obtain a JSON array of total values, but there doesn't yet seem to be an array valued function which can take the sum.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44997149/how-to-sum-values-from-a-json-field-in-mariadb-using-json-functions

Comment: check this post this person also extract sum. but I am unable to fetch total

Comment: Please share some sample input data, and the expected output from that data in **readable** form (not as an image) such that others can reproduce your problem

Comment: Are you using the [CONNECT JSON Table Type](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/connect-json-table-type/)?